# System of equations - solution for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Can I find a $C$, explicitly, for given $A$ and $B$ satifying $$ \sqrt{\pmb{t}^TAA^{T}\pmb{t}} + \sqrt{\pmb{t}^TBB^{T}\pmb{t}} = \sqrt{\pmb{t}^TCC^{T}\pmb{t}}, $$
for all possible choices of $\pmb{t}$.

The idea of taking different choices of $\pmb{t}$ to find an explicit solution of $C$ can be implemented, but I could not find $C$ **explicitly** in terms of $A$ and $B$ following this idea. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Note: $A$, $B$, and $C$ are real square matrices and $A^{T}$ indicates the transpose of the matrix $A$. Furthermore $\pmb{t}$ denotes a conformable column-vector.

Comment: The square roots make this problem a bit strange to me.  Can it generally be guaranteed (and is it well known) that such a $C$ exists?

Comment: I'm having trouble convincing myself that, in the $2 \times 2$ case, we can rewrite an expression of the form
$$
\sqrt{a_{11} x^2 + a_{12} xy + a_{22} y^2} + \sqrt{b_{11} x^2 + b_{12}xy + b_{22}y^2}
$$
into the form
$$
\sqrt{c_{11}x^2 + c_{12}xy + c_{22}y^2}
$$

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom, as you mentioned, $C$ may not exist at all. That is why I have started my question with "Can I find a $C$...". If you think such a $C$ does not exist, you may provide some logical reasoning supporting your statement.

Comment: your emphasis on *explicitly* made me think that there might have been some guarantee of existence

Comment: Use the singular value decomposition of $A,B$ to characterize when a solution exists. Notice that the level sets of the right-hand side should be ellipsoids, while the left-hand side wont be unless eigenvalues point in the same directions (too many bumps on the level set).

Answer (score 1):

Let $M = CC^T$.  Let $f(\pmb t) = \sqrt{\pmb{t}^TAA^{T}\pmb{t}} + \sqrt{\pmb{t}^TBB^{T}\pmb{t}}$. Our matrix $M$ is a symmetric matrix which meant to satisfy
$$
f(\pmb t)^2 = \pmb{t}^T M \pmb{t}
$$
for all vectors $\pmb{t}$. Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the standard basis vectors.  We note that
$$
e_i^T M e_i = m_{ii},\qquad (e_i + e_j)^TM(e_i + e_j) = m_{ii} + 2m_{ij} + m_{jj}
$$
Thus, if some satisfactory $M$ exists, it must satisfy
$$
m_{ii} = f(e_i)^2, \qquad m_{ij} = \frac 12 [f(e_i + e_j)^2 - f(e_i)^2 - f(e_j)^2] \quad i \neq j
$$

You should find it straight forward to write these expressions of $f$ explicitly in terms of the entries of $A$ and $B$.  For instance,
$$
m_{ii} = f(e_i)^2 = (|a_{ii}| + |b_{ii}|)^2
$$
the expression for $m_{ij}$ can be computed similarly.

Once you have this candidate $M$, it remains to be seen whether $\pmb{t}^TM \pmb{t} = f(\pmb{t})^2$ generally holds.

From $M$, $C$ can be obtained as the lower triangular matrix from the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) $M = CC^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|A|=\sqrt{AA^T}$, the unique positive semidefinite square root of $AA^T$. Define $|B|$ and $|C|$ analogously. The equation in question is then equivalent to $\||A|u\|+\||B|u\|=\||C|u\|$. Squaring both sides, we get
$$
\||C|u\|^2-\||A|u\|^2-\||B|u\|^2 = 2\||A|u\|\||B|u\| \ge 0.\tag{1}
$$
The LHS of $(1)$ is a quadratic form. Therefore, the original equation in question is solvable if and only if
$$
\||A|u\|\||B|u\| = \|Pu\|^2\tag{2}
$$
for some positive semidefinite matrix $P$. Note that if $(2)$ holds, we must have $\ker|A|, \ker|B|\subseteq\ker P$. But then for any $u\in\ker|A|$ and $v\in\ker|B|$, we would have
$$
\||A|v\|\||B|u\| = \||A|(u+v)\|\||B|(u+v)\| = \|P(u+v)\|^2 = 0.
$$
Therefore one of the kernels of $|A|$ of $|B|$ must be a subset of the other.

Suppose $\ker|B|\subseteq\ker|A|$. Let $V=\ker|B|^\perp$. Then $|B|$ is positive definite on $V$ and $|A|$ is positive semidefinite on $V$. Thus $(2)$ holds if and only if there exists a positive semidefinite matrix $S$ such
$$
\|Hv\|\|v\| = \|Sv\|^2\tag{3}
$$
for every $v\in V$, where $H=\sqrt{|B|^{-1}|A|^2|B|^{-1}}$ and $S=\sqrt{|B|^{-1}P^2|B|^{-1}}$ on $V$.

When $v$ is the unit eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of the restriction of $S$ on $V$, the RHS of $(3)$ is maximised. Hence the LHS must be maximised too and in turn, $H,S$ share a common eigenvector for their largest eigenvalues. Apply a similar argument on $\left(\ker|B|+\operatorname{span}\{v\}\right)^\perp$, we see that $H$ and $S$ also share a common eigenvector for their respective second largest eigenvalues. Continue this way, we see that $H$ and $S$ share the same orthonormal eigenbasis.

Let $\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2\ge\cdots\ge\lambda_k$ be the eigenvalues of the restriction of $S$ on $V$. Equation $(3)$ implies that $Hv=\lambda_i^2v$ whenever $(\lambda_i,v)$ is an eigenpair of $S$ on $V$. Now, if $u$ and $w$ are two orthonormal eigenvectors of $S$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$ respectively, then by putting $v=\cos(t)u+\sin(t)w$ in $(3)$, we get
$$
\sqrt{\lambda_i^4\cos^2(t)+\lambda_j^4\sin^2(t)}=\lambda_i^2\cos^2(t)+\lambda_j^2\sin^2(t)\tag{4}
$$
for every $t$. It follows that $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$. Hence $H$ is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix on $V$. But that means $|A|^2$ is a scalar multiple of $|B|^2$ on $V$. In turn, $|A|^2$ is a scalar multiple of $|B|^2$ on the whole Euclidean space, because $|A|=|B|=0$ on $V^\perp$.

In short, the original equation is solvable in $C$ only in the trivial case that one of $AA^T$ and $BB^T$ is a scalar multiple of the other.